# Sceenshot View have some error: Layout cannot be found

Tags: android, android-layout, io, android-view

i try to sceenshot `View`  but `R.id.layout` cannot be resolved or is not a field

and i try to  `import com.example.mye_card.R;` then clean up  but not work

```
    btnsave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            View v2 = findViewById(R.id.layout);
            v2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v2.getDrawingCache());
            v2.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            try {
                Date d = new Date();
                String filename  = (String)DateFormat.format("kkmmss-MMddyyyy"
                    , d.getTime());
                File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Pictures/" + filename );
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dir);
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                out.write(bos.toByteArray());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save card!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

error line

```
View v2 = findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

about import

```
package com.example.mye_card;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
```

Comment: What is this "layout" that you are trying to find?? if it is a android native resource, you should use `findViewById(android.R.id.layout)`

Comment: android.R.id.layout  not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is because you can't find the ID at the point of the context inside a `onClick` event.

Go on the top of your .java file, just after the starting of your `Class`, you probably will see some variables, so create a new variable:

```
View vDrawing = null;
```

Then, search for your `onCreate` method, and declare your variable:

```
vDrawing = (View) findViewById(R.id.layout);
```

Now, remove your declaration `findViewById()` from your `onClick` event and just use your variable previously declared `vDrawing` instead of using your `v2` variable.